# Adding a block snippet to a static block not working

Tags: module, static-block

Built a module with one block - List.php

```
class Pts_HireCms_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $productRange;
    public function loadCollection($productRange)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('hirecms/hire')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('product_range', $productRange)
                            ->setOrder('position', 'asc');
    }
    public function getHireProd()
    {
        return $this->loadCollection('Hire Prods');
    }
    public function getNonHireProds()
    {
        return $this->loadCollection('Non Hire Prods');
    }
}
```

Then I have a theme xml file of hirecms.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="hirecms/list" name="hireProd" template="hirecms/hire-prod.phtml" />
            <block type="hirecms/list" name="nonHireProd" template="hirecms/non-hire-prod.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and i've added:

```
{{block type="hirecms/list" template="hirecms/hire-prod.phtml"}}
```

to a static block, then on a category i've set display mode = static block only and cms block = to the one ive created.

However when i visit the route, the page loads but my block **{{block type="hirecms/list" template="hirecms/hire-prod.phtml"}}** is not being called.

Any ideas why?

I have this working perfectly on my local site, and the code has been pushed using github so no amendments along the way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try {{block type="core/template" template="hirecms/hire-prod.phtml"}}

Comment: Doesn't work either, no errors are being logged either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add my block type `"hirecms/list"` to System -> Permissions -> Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Block type should be `hireCms/list` with the capital C. 
Secondly it must be added to  `System -> Permissions -> Blocks`.